# Docker | How can I remove all containers but a certain few

Tags: docker, containers

I am interested in removing all of my containers but still be able to choose a few not to be removed.
I usually use the following:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

But this removes all of them. Is there a way to still use similar method yet choose certain containers (By their ID or any other way) that will not be removed?

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the `--filter` criteria available with [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

For removing only *exited* containers, for instance, I use

```
alias drmae='docker rm $(docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited")'
```

But there are other criteria:

```
-f, --filter=[]       Filter output based on these conditions:
                    - exited=<int> an exit code of <int>
                    - label=<key> or label=<key>=<value>
                    - status=(created|restarting|running|paused|exited)
                    - name=<string> a container's name
                    - id=<ID> a container's ID
                    - before=(<container-name>|<container-id>)
                    - since=(<container-name>|<container-id>)
                    - ancestor=(<image-name>[:tag]|<image-id>|<image@digest>) - containers created from an image or a descendant.
```

Comment: I think the grep -v I posted above is kinda easier for my needs.
Thanks though.

Comment: @ShayElmualem Sure. This is not a similar method (hence my answer using docker command option only), but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq | grep -v <containerID>)
```